# Changing the name of a Facebook app developer

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-developers

Is it possible to change the name of an app developer (which is shown here: http://appdata.com/apps/facebook/124024574287414-instagram)?

I have the name of the company in payment tab set to "A", name of the publisher is empty, but on AppData I see "C", whereas I do not see "C" anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AppData crawls your Facebook app and pulls the developer details along with the stats from there..

You can change the required fields only on Facebook's app developer page.

Comment: As I mentioned in second indention I do not see a field with such value, that appears in AppData.com

Comment: Well my best bet would be to check with the AppData support. I looked through the facts but seems they have missed to mention this.. Publisher field is something Appdata would never let the AppData user define. Not sure where they are pullin this details from Facebook..